# How is a system of axioms different from a system of beliefs?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, axioms

Other ways to put it: Is there any faith required in the adoption of a system of axioms? How is a given system of axioms accepted or rejected if not based on blind faith?

Comment: A system of axioms is usually (for example in the case of Group Theory, Ring Theory, Theory of Algebraically Closed Fields, $\dots$) a list of the fundamental properties of the objects one will be looking at. So associativity of multiplication just means one will not look at non-associative situations. There is a plethora of examples of structures that satisfy these axioms, no faith needed. The question becomes more complicated in a few cases, most notably axiomatizations of Set Theory.

Comment: Faith isn't required per se, just like it doesn't take faith to play chess. You don't *believe* those are the rules as if the rules are set in stone, you *define* them that way and *choose* to play the game accordingly. No faith is required because you aren't asserting that one system is better or more correct than any other: you're just picking them according to what you're interested in looking at.

Comment: Axioms are as a set of rules: you want to play? Abide by the rules of the game, or else don't play. Another difference with faith and religious beliefs is that nobody has yet be condemned to eternal hell, unspeakable suffering or the like by not accepting the rules of Euclidean Geometry, ZFC or Peano's Axioms...in fact, nobody has even been put to death by that, although the other way around has happened!

Comment: @DonAntonio: given the number of psychopaths bound to occur among as many people as there are in the world, I wouldn't be surprised if someone actually was put to death by that.

Comment: I take *faith* to mean *assume the truth of some rules or concepts, without the ability to either verify or contradict them.* E.g. faith in extraterrestrial life. Unless we can prove/disprove it (by exhibiting an instance of aliens, or exhaustively visiting every corner of the universe without finding them), it remains a belief; you can't show/deny what it entails. But when you *assume the truth of some axiomatic system,* you'd have the ability to show that it is consistent or inconsistent. You'd have the ability to calculate & play with the mathematical objects which the theory entails.

Comment: This reminds me an argument I and a (not mathematical) friend had one night in high school. His position was that mathematics was *"all about assumptions"* (he may have been jaded by a too-difficult physics class, if I am to armchair psychologize...). My position was that it is about exploring abstract *hypotheticals*.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Remember [Hippasus of Metapontum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus)!

Comment: Indeed @PerManne, yet this case is in the fringe zone of legend and sometimes it is said Hippasus was the one who got drowned, other times that he was the one who made the killing...anyway, that was 2,500 years and in the meantime we mathematicians have become more or less decent human beings, whereas people all around are still getting killed in the name of this or those gods, a tradition that already lasts more than 2,500 years...and I, at least, can't see end to it in the foreseeable future.

Comment: If you are interest in *foundational* aspects then you may find of interest expositions by professional mathematical philosophers, e.g. Penelope Maddy's [Believing the Axioms I](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms1.pdf) and [part II](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms2.pdf)

Comment: @Bill, thanks for the links. I have always found Maddy's articles enjoyable to read.

Comment: Beliefs can be true or false, but [mathematics is one big tautology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384861/is-mathematics-one-big-tautology). There's nothing to be taken on faith.

Comment: In pretty much every possible sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what sense are math axioms true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127158/in-what-sense-are-math-axioms-true)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To paraphrase Robert Mastragostino's comment, a system of axioms doesn't make any assertions that you can accept or reject as true or false; it only specifies the rules of a certain kind of game to play.

It's worth clarifying that a modern mathematician's attitude towards mathematical words is very different from that of a non-mathematician's attitude towards ordinary words (and possibly also very different from a classical mathematician's attitude towards mathematical words). A mathematical word with a precise definition means precisely what it was defined to mean. It's not possible to claim that such a definition is wrong; at best, you can only claim that a definition doesn't capture what it was intended to capture.

Thus a modern interpretation of, say, Euclid's axioms is that they describe the rules of a certain kind of game. Some of the pieces that we play with are called points, some of the pieces are called lines, and so forth, and the pieces obey certain rules. Euclid's axioms are not, from this point of view, asserting anything about the geometry of the world in which we actually live, so one can't accept or reject them on that basis. One can, at best, claim that they don't capture the geometry of the world in which we actually live. But people play unrealistic games all the time.

I think this is an important point which is not communicated well to non-mathematicians about how mathematics works. For a non-mathematician it is easy to say things like "but $i$ can't possibly be a number" or "but $\infty$ can't possibly be a number," and to a mathematician what those statements actually mean is that $i$ and $\infty$ aren't parts of the game [Real Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), but there are all sorts of other wonderful games we can play using these new pieces, like [Complex Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and [Projective Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry)...

I want to emphasize that I am not using the word "game" in support of a purely [formalist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(mathematics)) viewpoint on mathematics, but I think some formalism is an appropriate answer to this question as a way of clarifying what exactly it is that a mathematical axiom is asserting. Some people use the word "game" in this context to emphasize that mathematics is ["meaningless"](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/d/davidhilbe181560.html). The word "meaningless" here has to be interpreted carefully; it is not meant in the colloquial sense (or at least I would not mean it this way). It means that the syntax of mathematics can be separated from its semantics, and that it is often less confusing to do so. But anyone who believes that games are meaningless in the colloquial sense has clearly never played a game...

Comment: +1: Though it's somewhat disheartening to think of my projected field of study as a game, I suppose I should be glad about the fact that it's one of the most fun games I've had the opportunity to play!

Comment: So in what way does math differ from a religion then? If math can be compared to a game where axioms are the rules, couldn't the same be said for any religion? For instance, the 10 commandments would be the rules of christianity.

Comment: @Gabriel The 10 commandments would be a small subset of lemmas shared by Judeao-Christian religions. The axioms of Christianity would be more like "The origin of all existence (and the concept of existence itself) is God" and "Jesus is God".

Comment: The faith involved in religion is holding the position that these axioms are "true" of the reality we experience. Such a position is not necessary to participate in, for example, Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Gabriel: very very roughly speaking, we might divide religious claims into two broad categories. The first are claims about what kind of behavior is "right." This is a stronger statement than a statement which merely describes some kind of behavior; it is a claim that certain kinds of behavior will, for example, be rewarded in the afterlife and other kinds of behavior will not. The second are claims about the natural world, e.g. that the Earth is 6,000 years old. These are falsifiable. Mathematical axioms are not falsifiable because they do not make any claims about the natural world.

Comment: @Gabriel: in fact, mathematical axioms make no claims whatsoever. They are essentially definitions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan and what happens if I decide to use a different set of definitions? If all sets of definitions/axioms are equally valid, what does this say about the validity of mathematics?

Comment: Re: "It's not possible to claim that such a definition is wrong; at best, you can only claim that a definition doesn't capture what it was intended to capture": You can also sometimes claim that a definition is ill-founded. For example, consider a definition of *i* as "the real number such that *i* × *i* = 1". The problem is that this definition presupposes the existence (and perhaps uniqueness) of such a value, when in fact no such value exists (according to the standard axioms that this definition was, no doubt, intended to be consistent with).

Comment: @ruakh "when in fact no such value exists"... you must mean other than 1

Comment: @crf: And -1 . . . but no, I actually meant to type "the real number such that *i* × *i* = -1". (That is, more or less the ordinary definition of *i*, but throwing in the presupposition that it's a real number.)

Comment: @Gabriel: nothing happens. There is no notion of "validity" that is applicable to an axiom because, as I keep saying, an axiom does not claim anything. The worst things you can say about a set of axioms are that they are either inconsistent or uninteresting. But mathematics is much more than its axioms. Writing down axioms is only the very first step in doing mathematics via the axiomatic method; the next step is _proving things_ from those axioms. These proofs are what you can question the validity of.

Comment: Your defense about "maths having a meaning" is damn good. Allow me to repeat: "But anyone who believes that games are meaningless in the colloquial sense has clearly never played a game..." And +1 for the same.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How would you distinguish your usage of the word, "game," from a formalist's usage of it? For example, are you using "game" to reference *the reduction of mathematics to axioms and their logical consequences*, as opposed to *the reduction of axioms to sentences in formal languages and of logical consequences to rules of transformation between such sentences*?

Comment: An important observation (imo) is that any commandment is an imperative, while axioms are always declarative statements. So commandments, by any stretch of imagination, cannot be treated as axioms.

Comment: Harry Potter fans enjoy their time talking about the Harry Potter universe. That doesn't mean that the characters in Harry Potter are real, nor that discussions about the emotions of and relationships between the characters, the political struggles they go through, etc. aren't worthwhile to talk about. The same is true of mathematics. The difference with religion is that it asserts that certain statements are actually truths about our universe, i.e. that the Harry Potter universe is, in fact, our universe, meaning that Harry Potter is a real person who can really cast magic spells, etc.

Comment: See also, theology: even if one doesn't actually hold theistic views, discussion and exploration of the concept of god(s) and people's historical and current views on theism is still interesting, and can lend a lot of insight into the human condition. Mathematics does the same thing; the observations we make about the mathematical games we play can still provide insights that are *useful* in the real world, even if the particular rules of a particular game aren't a completely accurate reflection of the real rules of the real universe.

Answer (score 36):

The role of axioms is to describe a mathematical universe. Some settings, some objects. Axioms are there only to tell us what we know on such universe.

Indeed we have to believe that ZFC is consistent (or assume an even stronger theory, and believe *that* one is consistent, or assume... wait, I'm getting recursive here). But the role of ZFC is just to tell us how sets are behaved in a certain mathematical settings.

The grand beauty of mathematics is that we are able to extract **so much** merely from these rules which describe what properties sets should have.

Whether or not *you* should accept an axiomatic theory or not is up to you. The usual test is to see whether or not the properties described by the axioms make sense and seem to describe the idea behind the object in a reasonable manner.

We want to know that if a set exists, then its power set exists. Therefore the axiom of power set is reasonable. We want to know that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements, which is a very very reasonable requirement from sets, membership and equality. Therefore the axiom of extensionality makes sense.

What you should do when you attempt to decide whether or not you accept some axioms is to try and understand the idea these axioms try to formalize. If they convince you that the formalization is "good enough" then you should believe that the axioms are consistent and use them. Otherwise you should look for an alternative.

---

**Related:**

1. I talked about the difference between an idea and its mathematical implementation [in this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173002) which might be relevant to this discussion as well (to some extent).

Comment: Good to see a non-formalist answer/comment.

Comment: @Andre: I am a strongly agnostic person, in mathematics beliefs too. However in some sense I reject all forms of existence (including my own!). I am much closer to being a formalist in my tendencies; however in a strange way I hate when people look at mathematics syntactically. It's just not fun anymore when you take out all the semantics from math! :-)

Comment: +1: I'd give you +2 for leaving room for later "related" addenda, if I could. ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks, I already capped out for the day, so there's no point in +2 :-P

Comment: Am I correct in understanding from your answer that you think the genesis of math is indistinguishable from that of a religion then? If I change the word _axioms_ for the statement _a religion's belief system_ in your last paragraph, I get a direct parallelism between both.

Comment: @Gabriel: What? I'm not following this comment of yours. I made no actual comparison between mathematics and religion. This is beyond philosophy - this is theology. Axioms have a certain role in mathematics, to describe your playground. Religion and its dogmas have a different role -- to describe the system which keeps you from going to hell/turning into a gnat/etc.

Comment: I know you didn't @AsafKaragila, I'm doing it, it's the whole point of the question. When you say I should _decide_ whether or not to accept some axioms, it sounds like it's my choice to believe in math or not. Just like it is to believe in a given religion. So my issue with your answer is that I don't get how you differentiate a set of axioms from a set of beliefs if both require me to have _faith_ in them (which is another way to say to _accept_ them).

Comment: @Gabriel, consider Doron Zeilberger. He believes that there is a biggest number. He believes that the Peano axioms are wrong, maybe even inconsistent. This is his choice. You can accept axioms as reasonable or not; much like many people reject the axiom of choice because it has strange outcomes. It turns out, though, that the consistency of ZF and ZFC is the same, so in a way it doesn't matter if you assume choice. It is still a matter of personal taste what you assume to be the rules of the game. If you work in a certain theory long enough, it should be clear that you have accepted them.

Comment: @Asaf: you should be explicit about what I think you are doing here, which is deciding that "axiom" means "axiom of set theory (or logic, etc.)." I don't think this is a standard use of the word "axiom" in modern mathematics; nowadays we also talk about e.g. the axioms of group theory or ring theory, and it seems to me deeply silly to talk about "accepting" or "rejecting" these axioms. They are interesting games to play. You can choose to play them or not. But that choice does not entail any claim about either the natural world or some hypothetical Platonic reality.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I, as an extremely agnostic person, have the same attitude towards the axioms of ring theory or group theory as I have towards the axioms of set theory. For me axioms are the rules of the playground, and I play in the playground for as long as I wish. It doesn't matter whether or not I feel the axioms are good or bad, general or particular, when I need to use a certain system I do. I think that my philosophy touches *all* kinds of axiomatizations, and I feel that it represents them in a good way, and this is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In every set of axioms we pick we follow the same laws of logic? Can we construct a set of axioms and use different laws of logic (e.g. where law of excluding middle doesn't hold)?

Comment: @user599310: Sure, why not?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the answer. I asked this because when we argue about a topic we always use the classical laws of logic. I have opened a topic. I would be grateful to see your answer. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72595/contradictory-mathematical-axioms-and-laws-of-logic

Comment: @user599310: I don't have an account on that site. Sorry. To your question, let me point out that mathematics grew as a natural process alongside human history. The choice of axioms (including the logical one) is influenced by that, and was shaped through the aeons by utility and interest. If you can convince everyone to switch to an intuitionism tomorrow, that's great. If you can convince everyone to switch to a different foundation, also great. Both are unlikely, but these topics are studied on their own for their own interest, and these may influence our philosophy of maths in the future.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that faith is not required to accept the rules of certain game in order to play that game, I am pretty sure that, if the rules of the game, and the consequences of playing by those rules, were entirely arbitrary, a lot of mathematicians wouldn't be able to earn a living by doing mathematics.

For ex. according to some recent stats, mathematician is one of the most employable occupations in the U.S., mostly in finance industry. If that doesn't indicate that the rules have some validity in the real world, I don't know what does?!

Would physicists use mathematics if it were completely incapable to describe what they are theorizing and measuring?

There is *evidence* that axioms may be true, a lot of evidence.

EDIT:
I have found the following article by R.W.Hamming very illuminating:
[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Hamming.html)

Some quotations:

> The Postulates of Mathematics Were Not on the Stone Tablets that Moses Brought Down from Mt. Sinai.

also

> The idea that theorems follow from the postulates does not correspond to simple observation. If the Pythagorean theorem were found to not follow from the postulates, we would again search for a way to alter the postulates until it was true. Euclid's postulates came from the Pythagorean theorem, not the other way. For over thirty years I have been making the remark that if you came into my office and showed me a proof that Cauchy's theorem was false I would be very interested, but I believe that in the final analysis we would alter the assumptions until the theorem was true.

Amusingly, he warns in the introduction:

> I am well aware that much of what I say, especially about the nature of mathematics, will annoy many mathematicians. My experimental approach is quite foreign to their mentality and preconceived beliefs

Comment: Those are bad arguments. What evidence do you have that any axiomatic system talking about infinite objects is "true" in any sense of the word?

Comment: Not any. But the axiomatic system from which structures and relationships can be derived that get used everyday in almost all human endeavors certainly captures some truth about the world in which those endeavors occur.

Comment: Perhaps that should be a separate question: how is it that arbitrary rules of a game, that somebody may or may not choose to play, end up as the basis of a system having any relevance in the real world?

Answer (score 2):

One can believe a set of clearly contradictory statements (indeed, people often do). If it can be proven that a set of statements entails a contradiction, though, it certainly cannot be taken as an axiomatic system.

Comment: I mean, it _can_, it just isn't a very useful one.

Comment: I suppose arguably, since one can come to **any** conclusion one desires with a contradiction, it could be considered ***highly*** useful, in some sense. ;-)

I of course mean it can't logically be taken seriously.

Comment: [Speaking of which...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30437)

Answer (score 2):

There are similarities about how people obtain beliefs on different matters. However it is hardly a blind faith.

There are rules that guide mathematicians in choosing axioms. There has always been discussions about whether an axiom is really true or not. For example, not long ago, mathematicians were discussing whether the axiom of choice is reasonable or not. The unexpected consequences of the axiom like the well ordering principle caused many to think it is not true.

Same applies to axioms that are discussed today among set theorists. Set theoretical statements which are independent of the ZFC. There are various views regarding these but they are not based on blind belief. One nice paper to have a look at is Saharon Shelah's [Logical Dreams](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211398). (This is only one of the views regarding which axioms we should adopt for mathematics, another interesting point of views is the one held by Godel which can be found in [his collected works](http://www.oup.com/us/catalog/general/subject/Mathematics/Logic/?view=usa&ci=0198500734).)

I think a major reason for accepting the consistency of mathematical systems like ZFC is that this statement is [refutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) (to refute the statement one just needs to come up with a proof of contradiction in ZFC) but no such proof has been found. In a sense, it can be considered to be similar to physics: as long as the theory is describing what we see correctly and doesn't lead to strange things mathematicians will continue to use it. If at some point we notice that it is not so (this happened in the last century in naive Cantorian set theory, see [Russell's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)) we will fix the axioms to solve those issues.

There has been several discussion on the [FOM](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/mailman/listinfo/fom/) mailing list that you can read if you are interested.

In short, adoption of axioms for mathematics is not based on "blind faith".

Comment: It is rather meaningless to simply require consistency. After all, if ZFC is consistent then ( ZFC + not Con(ZFC) ) is a **consistent** theory, but people **never** adopt such a theory as foundational, although they often work with ( ZFC + Con(ZFC) ). There is an obvious reason, which requires much more than consistency, namely arithmetical soundness.

Comment: It is not. Consistency is equivalent to $\Pi^0_1$-soundness and many statements that people care about are $\Pi^0_1$. ZFC + Con(ZFC) is not adopted because it doesn't look natural, now replace Con(ZFC) with an equivalent axiom that looks natural and mathematicians may adopt it. Take e.g. PA. Con(PA) is equivalent to ordinal induction up to $\epsilon_0$, termination of Hydra game, etc.
Also keep in mind that Con(ZFC) doesn't really solve an issue, you then need Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)) and so on. 
Anyway this is a side point, the point is that axioms are not chosen on blind faith.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "It is not.". The fact that you say that people replace Con(ZFC) with an **equivalent** axiom shows that they do care about something **more than consistency**, since the theory they pick is the **same** as ZFC + Con(ZFC), and they never pick any axiomatization that gives the same theory as ( ZFC + not Con(ZFC) ). I also never said that ZFC + Con(ZFC) solves any issue, but that the clear preference for this is due to desire for arithmetical soundness. Indeed this agrees with your point that it is not blind faith, but having consistency is far from sufficient.

Comment: Note that arithmetical soundness does not **require** Con(ZFC), or any further up in the chain, but rather **forbids** ( not Con(ZFC) ). At the same time, arithmetical soundness is not necessarily **refutable** even if it were false, due to the incompleteness theorems. Precisely, if there is a program $U$ that accepts any arithmetically unsound theory (specified as a proof verifier), then we can decide the truth value of any arithmetical sentence $φ$ by running in parallel $U( PA + φ )$ and $U( PA + \neg φ )$. This is unlike consistency, which is always refutable if it is false.

Answer (score 0):

The best example is the Euclidean geometry and non-Eucliedean geometry. The first four postulates are common to these geometries and are rather elegant

1. A straight line segment can be drawn joining any two points
2. Any straight line segment can be extended indefinitely in a straight line
3. Given any straight line segment, a circle can be drawn having the segment as radius and one end point as center.
4. All right angles are congruent.

The fifth one did not share their grace

(5) If two lines are drawn which intersect a third in such a way that the sum of the inner angles on one side is less than two right angles, then the two lines inevitably must intersect each other on that side if extended far enough.

This postulate is not used in the first twenty-eight proposition of Euclid's Elements and it is a rather ugly duckling.

Euclid thought of this postulate to be inferior to the other four and certainly Euclid would have find it far preferable to prove this ugly duckling rather than to have to assume it. But he found no proof and therefore adopted it.

Over the centuries untold numbers of people gave untold years of their lives in attempting to prove that the fifth postulate was itself part of the four-postulate geometry.

Saccheri assumed the fifth postulate is opposite (he hoped he will find a contradiction) and worked with that as his fifth postulate and he got the hyperbolic geometry.

Non-Euclidean geometry was discovered in 1823 simultaneously, in one of those inexplicable coincidences by Janos Bolyai and Nikolay Lobachevskiy.

The meanings of "point", "line" and so on can be determined by the sets of theorems in which they occur and there are many geometries that have the first four axioms and they are all *internally consistent* but only Euclidean geometry is *consistent with the external world*.

This is from chapter IV, *Consistency, Completeness and Geometry* of Godel, Escher, Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid by Douglas H. Hofstadter

Comment: Was the link to the question posted earlier today on some website?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes it was posted on hacker news https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6621094

Comment: I see. That explains the votes that came out of nowhere (before the question was bumped). Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would submit the following: first, axioms in mathematics do not say anything about the Natural world, whereas beliefs usually do, I think. Second, for axioms, we know full well they are arbitrary and can be changed. I wouldn't say that we are "convinced" any axioms are "true". We know that axioms are an arbitrary set of givens we have chosen to derive some theorems, and it is part of the game to alter the axioms or consider a new set of axioms to derive other theorems. I think it is fairly different for beliefs where people would tend to be convinced the beliefs are "true"?

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone forcing us to use math always and only for reasoning about the actual world?

Counting seems practical. Certainly we spend lots of time learning about counting because it is known to be useful. Yet, those of us who are not particle physicists, where do we find anything in the actual world that can *really* be counted, that really has integrity in the manner of the integers (the counting numbers and their negatives)? Perhaps I'm counting watermelons. I'm not a plant biologist. Who am I to say that a watermelon is really one melon and not two melons, if it grows so constricted in the middle that the constriction is only full of rind? Even if no one has a definitive answer whether it is one melon or two melons, we need not conclude that learning to count was a waste of time. We could simply say that counting has many uses, just not this particular use.

Generally mathematical propositions are literally for the sake of argument. An axiom is a structure, little more than that. Perhaps an axiom gives to some otherwise undefined terms some otherwise meaningless names and claims that they satisfy an otherwise undefined relation. If we then reason out the consequences of this axiom, we do not thereby commit to the truth of any proposition in the actual world except perhaps the value of spending our time in this manner.

When we reach any logical conclusion from the axiom, we have found a proof that the axiom implies the conclusion. A proof is a structure. In finding a proof of a consequence, we have however not identified any actual or imagined objects for which the axiom is true.

When we do identify objects to correspond to the unknowns in an axiom, we have a model. Model theory is something other than proof theory. Even then we have not reduced the axiom to the model. In general there are many models for a particular proposition. A famous example is that Euclid's postulates (that is, axioms) of geometry, minus the one known as the "parallel postulate", provide valid but different models of geometry in the plane, on the sphere, or on a hyperbolic surface such as $z = x^2 - y^2$.

Answer (score -2):

I am going to go ahead and claim that there is in many ways not much of a difference.

As others here have explained very well, mathematical axioms can be seen as a set of rules and statements describing a mathematical system. And in similar terms, religious beliefs can be seen as a set of rules and statements describing the world we live in (or, as some state, don't actually live in).

However, the term "faith" is mostly meaningless (and, I would claim, irrelevant) as far as mathematics are concerned. To have faith that something is true requires that there is uncertainty about that truth. A lack of proof. Axioms do not need proof, they are the basis of proofs. To have faith in an axiom is pointless.

As for the question of accepting or rejecting axioms, I would claim this to be a moot point. There is no need to accept or reject any particular axiom because there is nothing stopping two mathematical systems coexisting, one with the axiom in question and one without.

Of course, for practical purposes one cannot explore an infinite number of systems, so the question becomes one of usefulness. Does this system, with these axioms, allow me to make useful or interesting statements, or does it not? Most systems will not. But some, like for example that of Euclidean geometry, have resulted in a vast number of useful statements.

The accepting and rejecting of axioms is an issue for religions only because religions tend to make statements not about their own system, but about the world. This is, according to me, the one important way in which mathematical and religious axioms differ: mathematical axioms only make statements about their own systems,  while religious axioms may (and often do) make statements about anything and everything.

Where mathematical systems can coexist because they each create their own little hypothetical universe, religions often can not and require faith because we only have this one universe which we insist on making statements about.

To see what happens when we instead start making religious-style statements about *another* universe, have a look at any well written fantasy or science fiction book. Suddenly axioms which may appear very religious if taken out of context become more mathematical in nature; like mathematical systems they define their own universe, and having "faith" in them once again becomes meaningless.

Comment: This is very formalist view of mathematics, arguably most mathematicians think they are finding truth about real world, not some fictional fantasies nor playing formal games. One of the major issues in the philosophy of mathematics is the applicability of mathematics to the real world problems e.g. google for "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in Natural Sciences". I think your answer is severely inadequate.

Comment: You are conflating two meanings of the word "rule" in your second paragraph. The rules that appear in religious doctrine are of a completely different nature from the rules that appear in mathematical axioms. The former generally dictate that some kinds of behavior _should_ occur and others should not. The word "should" does not exist formally in mathematics. Mathematical rules, in the axiomatic sense, are just definitions. They don't carry any normative weight whatsoever.

Comment: @Kaveh: Interpreting mathematics as describing the real world is quite a separate issue from what axioms are. The group axioms aren't expected to apply to the "real world": they're only expected to apply to *groups*. The real world only comes into play when we interpret a mathematical theory as describing the real world: the axioms of Euclidean geometry are collectively only expected to apply to Euclidean geometry, but we expect Euclidean geometry to apply to the real world. Asserting the parallel postulate is a truth about the real world is skipping a step!

Comment: @Hurkyl, There is a major difference between group theory axioms and axioms for set theory and arithmetic. There is no intended standard model for group theory, there are intended standard models for arithmetic and set theory. The goal of axioms for group theory is that they are applicable to many structures, the goal of axioms for set theory and arithmetic are to capture the intended model as much as possible.

Comment: How well these axioms capture the intended models is a different issue, but the intention is (and was) to capture those intended models. The views expressed in this answer are held by some mathematicians but arguably not by most of them. Particularly not by most of those mathematicians who think (or thought) about the axioms for set theory or arithmetic. There are many criteria that these people consider (or have considered) in deciding which axiom to accept as true (not in a mathematical model but really true, i.e. true in the intended standard models).

Comment: @Kaveh: That doesn't really contradict anything I've said: the difference you cite is not a property of the axioms, but how you intend to apply the theory they generate. That said, I did not intend to support the characterization of mathematics suggested by the answer, but instead to deny the opposite extreme.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I see, sorry if I misunderstood your comment. What I was trying to say was that particular sets of axioms e.g. those about sets and numbers are not arbitrary but aimed at capturing some intended models. You are right that this is not true for all axioms systems (e.g. group theory), I didn't mean to imply that is the case.

Answer (score -2):

One point that is missing in the other answers and that I believe is important is that mathematicians have adopted ZFC as their primary axiom system because it is useful for reasoning about the real world.

When discussions about this topic arise the main focus (probably rightly so) is to explain that the axioms and the resulting mathematics are "meaningless" (in the sense Qiaochu described) and that mathematics is more like a thought experiment or a game. And that is important, because it allows us to explain why the use of $i$ or the use of uncountable sets is indeed reasonable.

But on the other hand, ZFC excels at building objects that describe the real world. The real numbers are a great approximation of what we have in mind when we talk about *length*, statistics allow us to abstractly grasp uncertainty and physics as a whole describes reality in an eerily precise way. And even more important, the implications ZFC allows us to make about the behavior of these objects and concepts match our observations of the real world. That is, our logic, our axiom system and our meta-mathematics captures the way the real world "ticks".

Of course that is no accident: ZFC was build to capture as many concepts that mathematicians thought to be self evident as possible. But if we would live in a different universe we would probably adopt a different set of axioms. As such I understand an axiom system as a system of beliefs that may or may not be well grounded in reality. And I believe in ZFC in the way that I believe in physics: Even though it is totally arbitrary that our universe follows the mathematical concepts found by physicists, it has non the less proven to be a very good approximation.

Comment: I have yet to see how AC allows us to build objects that occur in the real world. If anything, I've seen AC build things that explicitly cannot exist. My mind will stand changed, however, once we double the sphere. I doubt this will be the most important thing in the world if we accomplish that though.