# Why is $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}}=X$?

Tags: arithmetic, intuition, inverse, fractions

Can someone help me understand in basic terms why $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}} = X$$

And my book says that "to simplify the reciprocal of a fraction, invert the fraction"...I don't get this because isn't  reciprocal by definition the invert of the fraction?

Comment: The reciprocal is by definition the *inverse* of the fraction --- and you calculate the inverse of the fraction by *inverting* the fraction.

Comment: The reciprocal of $a/b$ is defined to be the unique $x$ such that $a/b\cdot x=1$, denoted by $(a/b)^{-1}$ or $1/(a/b)$. As it happens, $x=b/a$ is a formula for it, which can be easily verified, but there is a difference between a definition and an obvious formula.

Comment: @user82306 I always ask my students, how many half pizzas in a pizza? The answer, $1/(1/2)=2$.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Maybe this will help you see why $\;\dfrac 1{\large \frac 1X}= X.\;$ We multiply numerator and denominator by $X$, which we can do because we can multiply any number by $\dfrac XX = 1$ without changing the actual value of the number:

$$\frac 1{\Large \frac 1X}\cdot \frac XX = \frac X1 = X$$
$$ $$

Answer (score 183):

$1/x$ is, by definition, the number that you multiply $x$ by to get $1$.

Similarly, $1/\left(1/x\right)$ is the number that you multiply $1/x$ by to get $1$.

But wait a sec: we just learned in the first sentence that that number is $x$.

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* rather than just demonstrating *how* by algebraic manipulation.

Comment: For this to be true, the inverse needs to be unique. And it *is* in the context of $\mathbb R^\times$, the group of non-zero real numbers under multiplication.

Comment: (+1) By the magic of democracy, the super-voted answer is indeed the one to heed.

Answer (score 32):

$$y=\frac1{\frac 1 x} $$
$$y'(x)=\left(\frac1{\frac 1 x}\right)' = -\left(\frac 1 {\left(\frac 1x\right)^2}\right)\left({\frac 1 x}\right)' = 
\frac 1 {\left(\frac 1x\right)^2} \cdot {\frac 1 {x^2}} = \frac {y^2(x)}{x^2}$$

So we have that $$x^2dy = y^2dx\\
\int \frac{dy}{y^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x^2}\\
-\frac{1}{y} = -\frac 1 x + C\\$$

Let's take a look at $y(1)$. $\frac 1 1 = 1$, this is already explained in a more common problem here: 
[Why is $n$ divided by $n$ equal to $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418794/why-is-n-divided-by-n-equal-to-1)
So $y(1)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}} =\frac 1 1 = 1$.

Note that I lost one possible solution, $y(x)=0$, by dividing by $y$. But since $y(1)=1$, it isn't really the solution.

Again: $y(1)=1$, so $~-\frac 1 1 = -\frac 1 1 + C ~~\Rightarrow~~ C=0$. Then $\frac {1} {y} = \frac {1}{x} \Rightarrow x=y$.

Comment: I'm sure OP will find this very helpful.

Comment: It seems people here love to make mathematical Rube-Goldberg machine.

Comment: I tried to explain it in more detail

Comment: Some of us (especially with cool names) still do appreciate. :-)

Comment: I think that understanding the question via this method is actually a conceptual step backwards.

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: I am pretty sure that in one of the derivatives evaluations you have already used that $\frac1{1/x} = x$, so your argument have a good chance of being cyclical.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you? Start with $${1\over1/x}$$ Multiply top and bottom by $x$:  $${1\over1/x}{x\over x}={x\over(1/x)x}={x\over1}=x$$

Answer (score 6):

Symbolically:
$$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}}=1\div \frac{1}{X}=1\times\frac{X}{1}=X$$
OR
$$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}} \times \frac{X}{X}=\frac{X}{1}=X$$
Intuitively:

We are asking how many 1/X pieces we can fit into a whole. Clearly there must be X of them!

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think this is a matter of **what is multiplication and what is division.**
First, we denote that
$$\frac{1}{x}=y$$
which means
$$xy=1\qquad(\mbox{assuming $x\ne0$ in fundamental mathematics where there isn't Infinity($\infty$)})$$
Now,
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{y}$$ by using the first equation. Here, 
by checking the second equation ($xy=1$), it is obvious that
$$\frac{1}{y}=x$$
thus
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 4):

Naturally, if we inverse some inverted object, we will have the object itself!
This matter take place for numbers and their operations:
$$-(-x)=x$$
and for any non-zero $x$ $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$$
(if we know "our limits" this fact is true for all objects in mathematics also for functions $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$, directions(vectors, matrices, ...) and so on.)

Answer (score 2):

Let, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = y$, where $y \neq x$. Now,

$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = y \\\Rightarrow 1 = \frac{y}{x}\\\Rightarrow x = y$

A contradiction! So, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = y$, where $y \neq x$ is false. So, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = x$

Comment: Wouldn't this work better as a direct proof?

Comment: Probably, but to some people 'indirect' way is more understandable than 'direct' way.

Answer (score 1):

I look at it this way. How do you check division? With multiplication.$\frac{15}{5}=3$ because $3\cdot 5=15$. Similarly, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$ because $x\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x\cdot 1}{1\cdot x}=\frac{x}{x}=1$

Comment: Here's another way I look at it: say $x=2$. $1\div\frac{1}{2}$ asks ``How many one halves fit inside one?" Well, two one halves fit inside one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that: $1/x=x^{-1}$
and also that: $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$

Therefore $1/(1/x)=(x^{-1})^{-1}=x^1=x$

Comment: $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$ is not always true but $1/1/x = x $ is always true $x\ne =0$.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers use algebra, but I prefer the intuitive explanation based on [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421620/why-is-frac1-frac1x-x?rq=1#comment901113_421620).

Suppose that you need to divide a large pizza for infants, who cannot safely  eat an entire pizza. Instead, each infant can eat only a slice. Each slice is smaller than the original pizza; so the size of each slice must necessarily be a fraction $< 1$.
In the picture below, each slice is $1/6$ of the original pizza.

[image]

Then $\dfrac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{forestgreen}{\dfrac{1}{6}}} = \color{red}{1}$ pizza divided by slices of size $\color{forestgreen}{\dfrac{1}{6}}$.

Well, what occurs if you divide $\color{red}{1}$ pizza totally into slices of size $\color{forestgreen}{\dfrac{1}{6}}$?
You end with 6 slices of pizza, after you cut the pizza per the 3 black straight lines as pictured above!

Answer (score -1):

Simply because:

$$
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{X}}=\frac{1}{(\frac{X}{1})^{-1}}=\frac{1}{1}\frac{X}{1}=\frac{1X}{1}=X
$$

And yes, the reciprocal of a fraction, is the inverted fraction...